# How to loop through two named lists and write non-homogenous data to a single xlsx sheet?

Tags: r, tidyverse, purrr

Say I have two lists like this:

```
listA <- list(
  df1 <- data.frame(
    Group = c('A', 'B'),
    Value = c(12, 10)
  ),
  df2 <- data.frame(
    Group = c('A', 'B', 'C'),
    Value = c(9, 8, 10)
  )
)

listB <- list(
  df1 <- data.frame(
    State = c('CA', 'WI', 'IA'),
    Value = c(13, 16, 5),
    Index = c(0.1, 0.11, 0.3)
  ),
  df2 <- data.frame(
    State= c('D', 'E', 'F'),
    Value = c(77, 83, 16)
  )
)
```

I want to loop through these, ideally with `purrr`, to sort of paste the corresponding dataframes into a single `xlsx` sheet for each shared list name. So `df1` in `listA` and `df1` in `listB` would be combined like the below in a tab called `df1`, with the same idea for `df2` in a separate tab:

[image]

This process would be repeated once for each dataframe name (`df1`, `df2`, etc.). Is there a way to achieve this using `openxlsx` and `purrr`?

Comment: Is it `listA <- list(df1 <- data.frame(...))` or `listA <- list(df1 = data.frame(...))`? Are the list-objectes named or identified by index?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming, your list elements are actually named, you could use a `for`-loop:

```r
library(openxlsx)

wb <- createWorkbook()

for (name in names(listA)) {
  addWorksheet(wb, sheetName = name)
  writeData(wb, sheet = name, listA[[name]])
  writeData(wb, sheet = name, listB[[name]], startRow = nrow(listA[[name]]) + 3)
}

saveWorkbook(wb, "test_file.xlsx")
```